# How to detect where iOS app was distributed from?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight, crashlytics

How can I detect where an iOS app was distributed from? I'd like to detect if it was through Apple's TestFlight, Apple's AppStore, or Beta by Crashlytics distribution platform.

Answer (score 3):

You can examine the `embedded.mobileprovision` file in your `.app` package. It is an s/mime / CMS signed plist, whose contents can definitely tell you whether the app was in-house, ad hoc or appstore. I haven't actually seen the plist for a test-flight build, although if you retrieve one, I'd love to see it.

You can either scrounge the plist out of the binary goo in the `.mobileprovision` file, or you can properly decode the file by implementing the equivalent of

```
openssl smime -inform der -verify -noverify -in embedded.mobileprovision
```

or

```
security cms -D -i embedded.mobileprovision
```

using the `Security.framework`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to know this. As others have said, the only way to do it would be to make different builds for each source.